# Error in Python Code Creating/Implementing Dictionary

Tags: python

Here's 2 programs, one to create a dictionary, and the other to implement it, the first one being:-

```
    class dictionary:
def _init_(self, pword=[]):
    self.word = pword

def addWord(self, nword):
    l = len(self.word)
    bp = -1
    for num in range(0,l):
        if self.word[num][0]==nword:
            return
        if self.word[num][0]>nword:
            bp = num
            break
    nl = [nword]
    self.word.append([])
    if bp>=0:
        for num in range(l-1,bp+1,-1):
            self.word[num] = self.word[num-1]
    else:
        bp+=1
    (self.word).insert(bp,nl)

def addKey(self, nword,key):
    l = len(self.word)
    for num in self.word:
        if num[0]==nword:
            if num.count(key)==0:
                num.append(key)
                return
    print("'"+nword+"' was not found in the present dictionary\n")

def display(self):
    if len(self.word)==0:
        print("Dictionary is currently Empty\n")
        return
    for num in self.word:
        for nw in num:
            print(nw+"\t")
        print("\n")
```

And the other one is

```
import file
def main():
print("Running file")
td = file.dictionary()
td.addWord("A")
td.addWord("B")
td.addWord("C")
print("Words added")
td.addKey("A",1)
td.addKey("A",2)
td.addKey("B",3)
td.addKey("C",1)
td.addKey("C",3)
print("Keys added")
td.display()

main()
```

Both the programs compile without a problem
But when i run the second one, i get the following error

```
Running file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Documents\Information Retrieval\ptrial.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Documents\Information Retrieval\ptrial.py", line 5, in main
td.addWord("A")
  File "E:\Documents\Information Retrieval\file.py", line 6, in addWord
    l = len(self.word)
AttributeError: 'dictionary' object has no attribute 'word'**
```

Comment: You do realize that there is the builtin and highly efficient `dict`, right?

Comment: Maybe it's an academic exercise.

Comment: I wasn't trying to re invent the in built dictionary. I had to create a new kind of dictionary to implement something known as a Postings list. Its used in Information Retrieval Projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class dictionary:
    def _init_(self, pword=[]):
        self.word = pword
```

The name of the special method is `__init__` with two underscores on each side, not just one. So this will cause the method to not being called automatically, not initializing the list.

You can use the builtin dict to emulate your “dictionary”:

```
class Dictionary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

    def addWord (self, nword):
        if nword not in self.dict:
            self.dict[nword] = []

    def addKey (self, nword, key):
        if nword in self.dict:
            self.dict[nword].append(key)
            return
        print('{0} was not found in the present dictionary'.format(nword))

    def display (self):
        if self.dict == {}:
            print("Dictionary is currently Empty\n")
        else:
            for k, v in self.dict.items():
                print('\t'.join(map(str,v)))
                print()
```

You actually don’t need `addWord` though, as you could just as well add the key on the fly whenever you call `addKey` on a `nword` which does not exist yet. You could then even use a `defaultdict` to make everything very simple:

```
import collections
class Dictionary (collections.defaultdict):
     def __init__ (self):
         super().__init__(list)

     def display (self):
        for k, v in self.items():
            print('\t'.join(map(str,v)))
            print()

td = Dictionary()
td['A'].append(1)
td['A'].append(2)
td['B'].append(3)
td['C'].append(1)
td['C'].append(3)
td.display()
```

Comment: Does this modified code allow me to append any number of keys to a given word?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the init method is `__init__` instead of `_init_` (see double underscore before and after).

```
def __init__(self, pword=[]):
    self.word = pword
```